We use Ubuntu Linux server as a log forwarder to our SIEM(Microsoft Sentinel), but the log has a time difference of 8 hours
The Source server is Ubuntu 20.04.6, whose time zone is UTC+0. The source Server send the log to a log forwarder server, which is also Ubuntu 20.04.6(Timezone is UTC+8). Then the log forwarder redirect the log to Microsoft Sentinel.
The Problem is that, the Sentinel shows that the real time log happened as 8 hours ago. For Example, the source log is 10:00am (utc+0), the sentinel will show as 2:00am(UTC+0).
I know that changing the source server's timezone to UTC+8 will solve the problem, but because of the business requriement, the source server's timezone needs to be set as UTC+0.
Is there anyway to handle this time difference problem?
I asked others to test the same scenario, they don't reproduce the same issue.
Thank you.

You would need to write a script to change the info time stamp before it is forwarded. Beyond any help on this site.

Doesn't this Sentinel thing have a way to configure what time zone sources are from? Or for your logging agent on the source to explicitly set the timezone in logs?

@DavidDE Thank you for the advice. Here need to confirm: in which part should I put the script? before the log arriving the log forwarder? or after the log arriving the logforwarder?

@muru Seems there is no place in Sentinel to set the timezone, I have confirmed with MS.

@user68186 Thanks for asking. The log forwarder is a linux server, ubuntu 20.04.6. What do you mean  by "not to touch the timestamp"? If the source log is utc+0, it will have the problem, if the source log is utc+8, it'll be no problem. But we could not change the source log's timezone to utc+8 because it will impact our other services.

Any body help me?

Is there anybody helping? Thx

No body knows this problem???

Can't believe that in such a big forum, there's no one can answer my question of Ubuntu......
